# ¿Cron Jobs acepta session_start()?

Tags: php, session, sesiones, cron

Mi código inicia así :

```
<?php
session_start('teste');

require '../Meli/meli.php';
```

y esto me responden:

> public_html/php-sdk-master/examples/logaem.php: line 1: ?php: No such
>   file or directory
>
> public_html/php-sdk-master/examples/logaem.php: line 2: syntax error
>   near unexpected token `'teste''
>
> public_html/php-sdk-master/examples/logaem.php: line 2:
>   `session_start('teste');'

¿Los cron jobs aceptan `session_start()`?¿cómo puedo usar una sesión en ellos?

Comment: [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)  espera por parámetro un `array` asociativo o simplemente no se le pasa nada. el  otro error parecen ser una ruta equivocada para el archivo `meli.php`

Comment: Mil gracias Alvaro.